# How to code the force quit app from alertDialog

Tags: android

I got the problem when quit the app from alertDialog. I saw one topic and tested but I couldn't. I also couldn't comment in that topic.

I start the app, intent to many activity. After playing, I back to home of the app and use Back button hard, AlertDialog will appear. But when I press positive, app will return to some activity, app is not quit or force quit.

Below is my code so please check:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to quit the game?");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class));
                finish();
            }
        });


        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

I've already tested with dialog.dismiss and system.exit instead of finish() but it's same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force stop an Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887429/how-to-force-stop-an-android-app)

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't comment in that. Also, I want quit from alertDialog, so how can I do?

Comment: have you tried finishAndRemoveTask() ?

Comment: Yes, I also tried finishAndRemoveTask() but it's same problem

Comment: ActivityC back to ActivityB and back to ActivityHome and press Back hard button to show dialog and press Yes, It will jump to ActivityB.

Comment: have you tried finishAffinity()?

Comment: I've already tested all from everyone. finish, finishAndRomoveTask, ... even I'm don't know exactly those function because I'm studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking, I changed one thing for all activity and it's working now.

In manifests, I change the tag `<activity android:.../>` instead of `<activity android:...></activity>`

Only difference `</activity>` I don't know why.